# Gensim Attribute Error when trying to use pre_scan on a doc2vec object

Tags: python, gensim

I am following the tutorial here:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-wikipedia.ipynb

But when I get to this part:

```
pre = Doc2Vec(min_count=0)
pre.scan_vocab(documents)
```

I get the following error on scan_vocab:

```
    AttributeError: 'Doc2Vec' object has no attribute 'scan_vocab'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known problem after a 2018 refactoring of the `Doc2Vec` code:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/2085

You can just skip that cell to proceed with the rest of that demo notebook. (If you really needed to adjust the `min_count` using the info from a full-scan, you might be able to call some internal classes/methods mentioned in the above issue.)